How to prevent child with text-overflow: ellipsis from expanding without setting a fixed width
I want both left and right to be 50% width. But when I have text-overflow ellipsis, it slightly expands the container past 50%. Setting a fixed px width on the sub containers fixes the problem, but I don't want to do that. I just want it to be 50% of whatever the root container is.


.container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 524px;
}

.row {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.sub1 {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
}

.sub2 {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sub1"><div class="sub2">Hello</div></div>
    <div class="sub1"><div class="sub2">Hello</div></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sub1">
      <div class="sub2">
        dfiedjef iejfi ejfiekjf e gregf rgfr trtretretret er terger
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sub1"><div class="sub2">Hello</div></div>
  </div>
</div>



